# urllib3 download a file using specified user agent

Tags: python, urllib3

What is the correct way to update the user agent information in `urllib3`?

How can I check that the user agent information was indeed changed and is being used?

For example:

```
user_agent = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'}
http = urllib3.PoolManager(10, headers=user_agent)

r1 = http.request('GET', 'http://example.com/')
if r1.status is 200:
    with open('somefile','w+') as f:
        f.write(r1.data)
```

When I create a `PoolManager` at `http` I looked at it by `dir(http)` and saw that `http.headers` was empty by default and updated to the user agent info specified, but is it being used? Is there anyway to check without having to look at `apache` logs?

And actually checking `/var/log/apache2/access.log` after trying to update the user agent:

```
>>> import urllib3
>>> user_agent = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'}
>>> http = urllib3.PoolManager(2, headers=user_agent)
>>> r = http.request('GET','localhost')
>>> with open('/var/log/apache2/access.log','r') as f:
...     last_line = f.readlines()[-1]
... 
>>> last_line
'127.0.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2014:20:42:04 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 461 "-" "-"\n'
```

Comment: There are a number of websites that will show you your user agent when you hit them.  You could try downloading one of those.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`header` argument should be `headers`:

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager(10, header=user_agent)
```

---

You can confirm that headers were set correctly using sites like `httpbin.org`:

```
>>> import urllib3
>>> user_agent = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) ..'}
>>> http = urllib3.PoolManager(10, headers=user_agent)
>>> r1 = http.urlopen('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/headers')
>>> print(r1.data)
{
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity",
    "Connect-Time": "1",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "Total-Route-Time": "0",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0",
    "Via": "1.1 vegur",
    "X-Request-Id": "5ef53f21-6caf-4e45-8123-98e417cd05ba"
  }
}
```

or you can use a packet analyzer (eg. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)).

Comment: How to change value of an specific header in an `HTTPResponse` object?

Comment: @SajadHTLO, in `HTTPResponse`? No, it's not possible.